# Windows creating unlimited folder within the folder with same name, can not delete it

Tags: windows-10

I am using windows 10. I want to delete the **folder3** folder on **D drive**

```
D:\folder1\folder2\folder3
```

There is a folder inside the folder3, say **n**

Now, my problem is, the folder **n** creating unlimited folder inside the folder **n** with the same name.

```
D:\folder1\folder2\folder3\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n......
```

I can not even delete any folder in the tree. I need to delete the complete tree from **folder1**.

Comment: Two possibilities. 1). The `\n` folders are symlinks to `\folder3` this would create an endless loop. You also need administrator privileges to delete symlinks under windows. 2). your file system is suffering oddly specific corruption. Run `chkdsk D:\folder1 /scan /forceofflinefix`, then restart.

Comment: please provide the command which you tried and its output so that we can understand what actually happens

Comment: CMD: `chkdsk D:\Installed /scan /forceofflinefix` || MSG: _The drive, the path, or the file name is not valid._ || My actual folder name is **Installed** (D:\Installed)

Answer (score 1):

Open an elevated command prompt

Make sure your prompt is set to D:

Type `rd folder1 /s /q` and press enter

The folder and all its sub-folders should now have disappeared.

Comment: As my folder name is Installed (D:\Installed), I have tried it. But showing the following error message:

Remove-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/s'.
At line:1 char:1
+ rm Installed /s /q
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Comment: That looks like a PowerShell error. Are you using CMD.EXE or power shell?